# Something wrong about matplotlib.pyplot.contour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` to draw a line, but the result is strange.
My python code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 1000

E = np.linspace(-5,0,N)
V = np.linspace(0, 70,N)
E, V = np.meshgrid(E, V)

L = np.sqrt(-E)
R = -np.sqrt(E+V)/np.tan(np.sqrt(E+V))

plt.contour(V, E,(L-R),levels=[0])
plt.show()
```

The result is:
[image]

But when I use Mathematica, the result is different.
Mathematica code is:

```
ContourPlot[Sqrt[-en] == -Sqrt[en + V]/Tan[Sqrt[en + V]], {V, 0, 70}, {en, -5, 0}]
```

The result is:

[image]

The result that I want is Mathematica's result.

Why does `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` give the wrong result? I am very confused!

It would be very appreciate if you can give me some idea! Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried not using the optional parameters for contour? Those could be causing these problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result given by `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` is numerically correct, but mathematically wrong.

Check what happens if you simply plot the `tan(x)`:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,1000)
y = np.tan(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

You will get a line at the poles. This is because subsequent points are connected.

You can circumvent this by using `np.inf` for points larger than a certain number. E.g. adding

```
y[np.abs(y)> 200] = np.inf
```

would result in

[image]

The same approach can be used for the contour.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 1000

x = np.linspace(0, 70,N)
y = np.linspace(-5,0,N)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

F = np.sqrt(-Y) + np.sqrt(Y+X)/np.tan(np.sqrt(Y+X))
F[np.abs(F) > 200] = np.inf

plt.contour(X, Y, F, levels=[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]